# Merging HDMI and USB to one cable

Tags: usb, usb-c, hdmi

I have a project which includes a display which has a mini-HDMI input and a USB-output (D+ D- differential pair) for touch screen.
How can I combine those two into one cable to talk to my MCU? I'm kind of having no idea on what to do here.
Should I make a USB-C hub?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Check the display documentation and see if it can return touch signals to the device through HDMI (just like the CEC signal that TV's returns through HDMI cable). Probably the display has separate USB output because it doesn't return touch screen's signals through the HDMI cable. Maybe the HDMI display and the touch are separate circuits in the display. Anyways, you would need colect and proccess the touch signals from HDMI, what seems to be more complicated than use USB. The last solution would be use electricians' tape to tie HDMI and USB cables together, in order to make just "one cable".

Comment: This is hard enough that I would buy separate cables and heat shrink them together.

Comment: @mguima HDMI has no method of transferring USB or touch info.

Comment: Note, also, that I'm not aware of anything that I would call an "MCU" that speaks HDMI. Sure, application processor SoC, or special purpose video processor SoC might also contain programmable processors, but is this really what you meant when you said "MCU"? HDMI is so fast that it's basically out of the reach of most microcontrollers to do anything *useful* with it.

Comment: I think I need to clarify further this.
I do have a SoC that output LVDS signal. My screen has a 40-pin FPC connector that receives 3-lane or 2-lane MIPI + a separate touch with USB signal.
So the screen manufacturer provides me a small PCB that: a. accept HDMI signal and convert it to MIPI; b. transfer the USB signal through a small USB-B port.
My problem is that, the SoC is sitting inside a Box and I need to connect such box to the screen using a cable

Comment: And who is making HDMI out of LVDS?

Comment: @Justme Surely it hasn't.